# Display another image for mobile using css

Tags: html, css, background

```
.bg-img-1 {
  background: url("../images/bg-img-01.jpg"); 
}
```

This is loading the background image in the site and I want to display an another image for mobile displays. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried media query? [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries in your css:

// default image

```
.bg-img-1 {
  background: url("../images/bg-img-01.jpg"); 
}
```

// for tablets and above

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .bg-img-1 {
     background: url("../images/bg-img-01-tablet.jpg"); 
  }
}
```

you can use multiple media queries for different screen resolutions.

Comment: i have a form in the body. When i enter this code in css file. The form becomse a basic form ( the css for the form doesn't work)

Comment: @Hard Byte check curly brackets if are all closed. Maybe you copied my answer without the last. So I edited my answer.

Comment: i did. it solved the problem but it still shows the default image
My index.php: ``<div class="page-wrapper bg-img-1 p-t-100 p-b-100">
        
        <div class="popPictureParent" id="picture1">``
css: https://pastebin.com/Fg2BhBE5

Answer (score 0):

you can used media and to another size review another image

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
.bg-img-1 {
  background: url("another image"); 
}
}
```

Comment: i have a form in the body. When i enter this code in css file. The form becomse a basic form ( the css for the form doesn't work)

Comment: you insert in head style tag <style></style> .and there used css file and work it

Comment: and add this element in top

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: it still shows the default image My index.php: ``<div class="page-wrapper bg-img-1 p-t-100 p-b-100"> <div class="popPictureParent" id="picture1">`` css: pastebin.com/Fg2BhBE5

Answer (score -2):

You need to use media queries :)

For computer queries, you use one image, and for mobile queries, you use an other image :) Check W3C it can help you :)